# How to install an apk from inside my app?

Tags: java, android

I've been stuck on this for 2 days.

All I want is for the app to install an apk. I placed the apk inside the `raw` resource directory.

Update: Thanks to @MarcosVasconcelos below code is now working.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

<application>

    <provider
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.goodweathercorp.boost.fileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

*paths.xml* in res>xml:

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/"/>

</paths>
```

In Activity:

```
if (getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
    
    File file = new File(getCacheDir()+"/longer.apk");
    if (!file.exists())
        try {

            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("longer.apk");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);

            fos.write(buffer);


            inputStream.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    else Log.e(TAG, "File already exists");

    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".fileProvider", file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    try {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I tried all variants of the String path, including using the Resource Id and adding the ".apk" file extension. I always get the `ActivityNotFoundException` error. Perhaps an apk shouldn't be placed in the `raw` folder? If so where would it be placed to get a working Uri?

Comment: Probably the Activity not found is for the intent Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE) not your apkUri, also note that you are totally using only if you cannot install packages:
```!```getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls(), have you requested the user permission?

Comment: Use a ContentProvider uri to provide the file to the argument

Comment: The only way to share a file from within your application is providing a ContentProvider in your Android manifest, from your code you create a URI from getContentResolver() and share the Uri trough the intent. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider

Comment: I think its more complete https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Updated the OP to working code. I just have one more question: I used `byte[] buffer = new byte[size];` where `size` is the entire size of the input stream. I read that this might cause an OutOfMemory exception. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: yes theres a better approach the idea of the size is buffering chunks so use a size of 1024 and a loop like here:
            ```int count = 0;while (true) {
                count = inputStream.read(buffer);
                if (count <= 0)
                    break;
                fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }```

Comment: Well I gonna add my comments as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way to share a file from within your application is providing a ContentProvider in your Android manifest, from your code you create a URI from getContentResolver() and share the Uri trough the intent. developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider

Good implementation example: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing

EDIT: theres a better approach to read a stream, the idea of the `size` is buffering chunks, so use a size of 1024 and a loop:

```
   int count = 0;
   while (true) {
       count = inputStream.read(buffer);
       if (count <= 0) break;
         fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
```

Comment: Tried this but it results in the error that there was a problem parsing the package when trying to install it